# Part of the Interface disappeared

Tags: interface, sculpting

while I was sculpting today a part of my interface disappeared while accidentally hitting a key combination I don't remember. The interface only changed in Sculpting mode and it only changed in this project, it's back to normal when I open a new project. Is there a way to fix this? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. The shortcut maximizes the view of the window you are hovering over.

**Note :** If you emulate a 3-button mouse, the shortcut is <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

Press this combination again to go back to normal.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Even though it was Alt+CTRL+Space, probably because I have emulate 3 Button mouse active